How can i upload a large xml about 12G using kendo upload control in AngularJS?
I have a large xml that i want to upload using the Kendo upload control.
$("#srcFile").kendoUpload({
    multiple: true,
    async: $scope.asyncsettings,
    files: $scope.srcfile,
    complete: $scope.srcComplete,
    success: $scope.srcSuccess,
    upload: $scope.srcUpload,
    error: $scope.srcError,
    select: $scope.srcSelect
});

How can i upload it using batches . Do i need to put it in the srcUpload routine ?
I have tried to increase RequestSizeLimit in the MVC Control, but it says the assembly is not recognised. I am using .net framework 4.8 ?
